# On the notation of measures

Tags: measure-theory, mathematical-physics

I have come across some measures, such as the [Lioiuville Measure](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvilleMeasure.html), where the definition is often given in terms of other variables in differential notation. For example:
$$d\mu = \prod_i dp_i\,dq_i.$$

I have seen this notation when a measure is defined in terms of another measure. For example, say $\mu$ is a measure, then we may define $d\nu = f d\mu$ for some $\mu$-measurable function $f$ by
$$\nu(E) = \int_E f d\mu.$$

However, I have not seen it written solely in terms of variables as opposed to measures. This seems to be common in mathematical physics. In the case of the Liouville measure, we are defining the measure in terms of momenta and position. My intuition tells me that, taking $i = 2$,:
$$d\mu = \prod_i d\,p_i d\,q_i \implies \mu = \iint dp_i dq_i.$$

Is this the case? If so, is this integral to be interpreted as a Riemann integral, as we are integrating with respect to a variable as opposed to a measure? This seems unlikely, so I suspect we are instead using the Lebesgue measure. If that is the case, how do we compute such integrals with respect to say momenta?

Comment: $d\mu=\prod_{i=1}^ndp_idq_i$ is Physicists' shorthand for saying $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$ (which is the completion of the $2n$-fold product of the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$; or alternatively you could just work on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and forget about completions). Though really what is happening in the background is that in Hamiltonian mechanics, one has a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, and locally there are these special coordinates (Darboux coordinates) such that $\omega=\pm\sum_{i=1}^ndp_i\wedge dq^i$ (signs are notorious here).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you! So there is nothing special about the coordinates being momenta and position, it is simply the $2n$-product Lebesgue measure?

Comment: and then $\mu$ is the measure induced by the volume form $\frac{\omega^{\wedge n}}{n!}=\pm dp_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dp_n\wedge dq^1\wedge\cdots \wedge dq^n$.

Comment: right, as long as you work in one set of 'nice coordinates', that's all it is.